# Through this piece of code i want to collect sample of face but it is giving error

Tags: python, python-3.6, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy 
face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/my pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

def face_extractor(img): # to extract face feature
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces= face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray,1,3,5)

    if faces is():     
        #if there is no face on screen
        return None

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:  # if face present, crop face,return it
        cropped_face = img[y:y+h,x:x+w] 

    return cropped_face    

cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)  # to open camera
count = 0 


while True:
    ret ,frame = cap.read()
    if face_extractor(frame) is not None:
        count += 1
        face = cv2.resize(face_extractor(frame),(200,200))
        face = cv2.cvtColor(face,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        file_name_path = 'C:/Users/my pc/faces/user' + str(count)+'.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(file_name_path,face)  

        cv2.putText(face,str(count),(50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)  #count how mnay pics clicked
        cv2.imshow('face cropper',face)

    else:
        print('face not found')
        pass

    if cv2.waitKey1 == 13 or count == 100:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print('collecting samples complete')
```

**below is the error**

```
ace.py:9: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if faces is():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face.py", line 24, in <module>
    if face_extractor(frame) is not None:
  File "face.py", line 7, in face_extractor
    faces= face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray,1,3,5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-j8nxabm_\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

Comment: Just read the error. There's nothing like `is()` in python as far as I known. If you are checking the presence of `face` by using `is` keyword then its a syntax error. Try using `==` as said in error. Also you are not clear what is it getting compared too. Seems a copy pasted code from somewhere which you have mistaken. It might be `if faces is some_func()`

Comment: maybe you means `if faces is None:` ? Or if you get list `if len(faces) == 0:` In both situations you can use shorter `if not faces:`

Answer (score 1):

Error message shows problem with `if faces is():` because there is no `is()` in Python.

`detectMultiScale()` gives list with objects and you can check if this list is empty:

```
if len(faces) == 0:
    return None
```

or more readable

```
if not faces:
    return None
```